# Integrating over region bounded by two ellipses

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, conic-sections

> Let $D$ be the region in the first quadrant which is bounded by the ellipses $4x^2 + y^2 = 16$ and $4x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Calculate $$\int\int_D\frac{x}{4x^2 + y^2}dA $$

What would be the best way to approach this problem? Preferably no elliptic  coords as those haven't been covered in our class. Im thinking a change of variables could be a good choice. If you decide to do one please explain how you came up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the second ellipse is all inside the first one, you have
$$
\iint_D\frac{x}{4x^2 + y^2}dA=
\iint_{E_1}\frac{x}{4x^2 + y^2}dA-
\iint_{E_2}\frac{x}{4x^2 + y^2}dA.
$$

Comment: How do you integrate over either of the ellipses without using elliptic coords though?

Comment: @Pame The integration is easy. Use Cartesian. No need to change variables. Do "dx" first.

Comment: @Pame Find $x$ as a function of $y$ for both ellipses and integrate in $dxdy$.

Comment: @Pame Because this integral is donut.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you suggest setting up this for the larger ellipse$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{16-y^2}{4}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{16-y^2}{4}}}\frac{x}{4x^2 +y^2}dxdy$$ Can't this only be solved numerically?

Comment: No, it can be done easily: $x$ integration gives a logarithm. And notice that lower bound for $x$ and $y$ is $0$ (first quadrant).

Comment: Ok so computing this gives me approx $0.63$. Answer should be $\frac34$ so its close but not quite.

Comment: I noticed another mistake in your integral: upper bound for $y$ is $4$, not $2$. I've just checked and the result is indeed $1$ for the first integral and $1/4$ for the second one.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the transformation $x=\frac12r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, so that $4x^2+y^2=r^2$. Your integral is then equal to $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^4{r\cos\theta\over 2r^2}\frac r2\,dr\,d\theta = \frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^4\cos\theta\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: How did you find the bounds for $r$? Doesen't this mean you're integrating over a circle? Also Im assuming $r/2$ is the jacobian?

Comment: @Pame The point of this substitution is to transform the ellipses into concentric circles. The bounds for $r$ are evident by inspection.